# Почему переменная созданная в функции не отображается в контексте этой функции?

Tags: javascript

Почему переменная созданная в функции не отображается в контексте этой функции?
Переменную test2 не могу найти в контексте this, как её там найти? и почему её нет? если она есть, то где?

```
 var test1;
    console.log(this);
    
    function testthis() {
        var test2=10;
        console.log(this);
    }
    
    testthis();
```

Comment: переменна объявленная через `var` не попадает в контекст `this` внутри функции. Объявите без `var`, тогда будет работать ( потому что тогда переменная попадет в window, а по умолчанию у функции this = window )

Comment: если переменная обьявлена без var, let, то она считается сразу глобальной в любом месте?

Comment: если переменная объявлена без `var`, `let`- это ошибка. Её надо исправлять или оставить. То что так работает не говорит так делать.

Comment: в строком режиме такое будет работать обьявление без let и var? и почему так нельзя делать?

Comment: Потому что вы путаете область видимости переменных (scope) и контекст выполнения функции (this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function testthis() {
  this.test2 = 10;
  console.log(this);
}

testthis.call({test1: undefined});
```